# SHA1 different key problem on Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have this application which was made in 2015. I have updated that application and now I want to upload the updated version to play store. But unfortunately, it is giving me an error that the SHA1 key is different. I am attaching the image below. [Play store console  SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHgIA.png)

Furthermore, the organization that I am working for, does not have any information about the key store password or Alias. There is literally no information about the previous version. Therefore, I am totally clueless how to update this application in google play store

Comment: This link may help you. Please check : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/forgot-keystore-passwordjks-file-you-can-still-recover-it

Comment: if  you have opt for app signing in playstore you can update by creating new jks .read more here.... https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Without SHA1 Key you can not generate another Signed APK to upload . You must need that key in order to generate new signed APK to Upload .

Google will not re-sign any of your existing or new APKs that are signed with the app signing key. This enables you to start testing your app bundle in the open, closed, or internal test tracks while you release your existing APK in production without Google Play making any changes to it.

Comment: Create New One and Remove the App from Google playstore and Upload new Signed APK

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that the you are trying to generate a signed apk using a different certificate than the one that was used to sign the original apk. If you cant get a hold of the hold certificate you will have to create a new one (what I think you have already done), generate a signed apk then publish it as a new app on the play store. You will have to un publish the old application though. Try using a slight change in the package name like  a change from small letter to capital letter eg from "com.example.company" to "Com.example.company"

Answer (score 1):

It is precisely this problem that caused Google Play to introduce [Google Play App signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#google-play-app-signing). If your app is opted in, then Google looks after your signing keys, and if you lose the information, then Google Play support can help you change the upload key.

However, if you are not opted in to Google Play app signing there is nothing you can do.

The best option is, as other people have said, unpublish the old app, create a new one, and this time opt in to Google Play App Signing so it doesn't happen again.